# WSO2 ESB - Iterator / Loop

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to Iterate through the elements of the xml file and call the sequence for each iteration without a send mediator within the Iterator. [Similar to Iterator Mediator without Send Mediator within it]

### XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Files><File>testValue1</File><File>testValue2</File></Files>
```

### Expected Iterator:

```
   <iterate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="$ctx:test//File" id="UTMIterator" sequential="true">
      <target>
         <sequence>
            <property name="InsideSeq1" expression="//File"></property>
                <class name="samples.mediators.SimpleClassMediator">
                   <property name="varible1" expression="$ctx:InsideSeq1"/>
               </class>
            <log level="custom">
               <property name="text" value="***** Inside Iterator *****"></property>
            </log>
         </sequence>
      </target>
   </iterate>
```

## Sample:

```
    <iterate xmlns:ns="org.apache.synapse/xsd"; expression="$ctx:test//File" id="UTMIterator" sequential="true">
<target>
 <sequence>
    <log level="custom">
      <property name="text" value="***** Inside Iterator **"></property>
      <property name="InsideSeq1" expression="//File"></property>
      <property name="text" value="** Inside Iterator *****"></property>
    </log>
 </sequence>
</target>
</iterate>
```

Note: Iterating the xml without the send mediator.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. It is not a must to have send mediator.

Comment: But control is not coming out of the loop. Keep waiting, any property to be removed? like 'To'

Comment: Might be your class mediator blocks the flow. what you are doing in your class mediator?

Comment: For simple flow removed the class mediator, having only sequence as below:      <iterate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="$ctx:test//File" id="UTMIterator" sequential="true">
      <target>      
         <sequence>
            <log level="custom">
               <property name="text" value="***** Inside Iterator *****"></property>
               <property name="InsideSeq1" expression="//File"></property>
               <property name="text" value="***** Inside Iterator *****"></property>
            </log>
         </sequence>
      </target>
   </iterate>

Comment: Hi Ratha, Any suggestion.     [Using Proxy Service,inside inSequence]

Comment: Can you provide your full insequence logic? with iterate/and other mediators?Edit your original question with the full sequence configuration

Comment: Thanks Ratha, I think it needs the attribute continueParent="true" in the Iterate for coming out of the loop.

Comment: Are there any examples how to use send mediator in interate mediator and continue the loop only after the response came along?